# What is the velocity of a sinking glass object

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, water, velocity, speed

This is really urgent and I couldn't solve it myself, no matter how I tried.

I need to the rate at which an object will sink into the bottom of the sea.

The objects volume is: 0.002795 cubic metres and the density is: 2500kg/m3. Its made of glass and has a rectangular tank form (0.4x20x0.0325m).
The water's density used for the calculation should be 1240kg/m3

Thanks in advance,
Chris.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: That's not homework, I have to calculate this for my mother's artwork.

Comment: What have you done so far? Can friction be neglected?

Comment: I've tried calculating it with Stoke's Law but I get 6km/s, because  it's meant for small spheres. Friction shouldn't be neglected as I need an answer as close to reality as possible.

Comment: 6km/sec is obviously not the terminal velocity of such an object. Note that you wrote (0.4x20x0.0325m), whereas the volume you wrote, 0.002795m^3, comes from 0.2m, not 20m. Did you use that mistaken 20m in your calculations? (And yeah, your geometry (not small spheres) makes a difference, but not 6km/sec worth.)

Comment: ehh, that was a mistake, it's actually 0.2, just I wrote that wrong above

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the [drag coefficient $C_D$ for a rectangular block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_coefficient) and to assume that the resistive force is proportional to the square of the speed.
As an order of magnitude you can say that for a rectangular block the drag coefficient is approximately equal to one but you can search for a better estimate by googling [drag coefficient rectangular block](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/drag-coefficient-d_627.html) as an example of one such site.

So now equate the downward force $(\rho_{\text{glass}} - \rho_{\text{water}})Vg$ to the drag force $\frac 1 2 C_D \rho_{\text{glass}} v_T^2$ where $v_T$ is the terminal speed of the glass block, $A$ is the area of the block resented to the water ie related to the orientation of the block) and $V$ is the volume of the block.

This will give you an estimate of the terminal speed.